# Can't View Custom Zones in CloudKit Dashboard

Tags: cloudkit, ios10, xcode8

I can't seem to get the CloudKit Dashboard to display my custom zones for my container.

I'm using Xcode Beta 8.3 and the iOS 10 SDK.

In my test app, I successfully create records in the private database in my custom zone. I can also retrieve those same records once I have created them.

However, the dashboard stays the same:

[image: "No private zones"]

Is there something I need to check in my settings, is this a temporary beta software thing, or is it something else?

Thank you

Comment: Are you creating the zones in the same account that you used to log into CloudKit dashboard? Usually the private data section also shows the default zone for your user

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was not using my developer account of the simulator. I'll accept your answer if you post it below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're logged into the same account on your dashboard as the one on the device that you're testing on!